# Questions on the construction of a Noetherian domain that is not an N-1 ring

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, examples-counterexamples

In [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagata_ring) there is an example I'm trying to understand.  The same example seems to appear in two articles, actually.

The relevant definition is

> An $N$-$1$ ring is an integral domain $A$ whose integral closure in its quotient field is a finitely generated $A$ module

The example is

> If $R$ is the subring of the polynomial ring $k[x_{1},x_{2},...]$ in infinitely many generators generated by the squares and cubes of all generators, and $S$ is obtained from $R$ by adjoining inverses to all elements not in any of the ideals generated by some $x_{n}$, then $S$ is a 1-dimensional Noetherian domain that is not an $N$-$1$ ring.

First off, I think it makes sense that $R=k[\{x_i^2\mid i\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{x_i^3\mid i\in\mathbb N\}]$.  Already it seems like its integral closure should be $R_0=k[\{x_i\mid i\in\mathbb N\}]$ which would seem to be not a finitely generated $R$ module.  **So this is already a domain that isn't N-1, right?**

My second question is what is meant by the rest of the construction. Let $M_1$ be the multiplicative subset of $R_0$ that is the intersection of complements of ideals of the form $(x_i)$, and let $M_2=M_1\cap R$.  **Am I interpreting this correctly that $S=RM_2^{-1}$?** If I'm reading that right, then **how do I see that it makes $S$ $1$-dimensional and Noetherian?**

$R$ itself does not look Noetherian, since you can generate an infinite ascending chain whose terms are sums of the first $n$ ideals of the form $(x_i^2, x_i^3)$. That also seems to show $R$'s Krull dimension is infinite.  I'm not very clear on how the localization step fixes this in $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that $R$ is already not N-1: the integral closure is $k[x_1,\cdots]$ which is not finitely generated over $R$, as any finite collection of generating elements would only be able to express finitely many of the $x_i$.

I agree with your interpretation that $S=M_2^{-1}R$. To see that $S$ is one-dimensional, the intuition is that localizing at $M_2$ removes any subvariety of $\operatorname{Spec} R$ which is contained in two or more of the subvarieties $V(x_i^2,x_i^3)$, leaving you with only these sets as proper subvarieties, which gives dimension one. Indeed, if $I\subset R$ is an ideal which contains both $I_i=(x_i^2,x_i^3)$ and $I_j$ for some $i\neq j$, then it intersects $M_2$ and $M_2^{-1}I=S$. So every prime ideal of $S$ comes from a prime ideal of $R$ which contains at most one $I_i$, and it is not so hard to show that such an ideal must actually be $I_i$ or $0$. Therefore the only prime ideals of $S$ are $0$ and $M_2^{-1}I_i$, and as the only nontrivial inclusions among these are $0\subset M_2^{-1}I_i$, $S$ is of dimension one. Further, as any ring where any prime ideal is finitely generated is noetherian and all of these ideals are finitely generated, we have that $S$ is noetherian.

(For what it's worth, I agree with your arguments in the final paragraph too.)

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning a lot from this!  The effect of localization is a lot more clear now.

Comment: Actually I've found reasoning about $k[x^2,x^3]$ already pretty challenging. I'm not even sure I completely understand why $R$ is not integrally closed. If, for example, we just used $k[\{x_i^2\mid i\in \mathbb N\}]$, one would be tempted to say "look, $X^2-x_1^2$ does not have its root!" and yet that ring would be isomorphic to $k[x_1,x_2,\ldots]$ which is integrally closed.  What is it about having both the squares and the cubes that breaks closure?

Comment: Sorry, just realized I had made some errors before - hopefully the correction isn't totally awful and intuition-destroying. The point with localization is that if $R\to S$ is a localization and $r\in R$ becomes invertible in $S$, then $V(r)\subset\operatorname{Spec} R$ has empty preimage in $\operatorname{Spec} S$ under the natural map $\operatorname{Spec} S\to\operatorname{Spec} R$, because invertible functions can't vanish at any point.

Comment: As to your 2nd comment, the issue with your example is that $T^2-x_1^2$ doesn't have any roots in $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ - integrally closed in the field of fractions is the statement that if $p(T)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $R$, any solution over $\operatorname{Frac}(R)$ must actually be in $R$. The way this breaks for $k[x^2,x^3]$ is that $x^3/x^2$, a perfectly good element of the fraction field, satisfies the equation $T^2-x^2$. It can be easier to think about this example as the coordinate algebra of the curve $y^2=x^3$ - then you can connect integrally closed to smoothness.

Comment: I think what I'm picking up on is the difference between $k[x^2]$ being integrally closed in its own field of fractions, and it not being integrally closed in $k(x)$.  It's a weird distinction.  Thanks for reminding me of the $x^3/x^2$ thing... i've seen that somewhere before and now it's coming back to me! That's how "x gets into the integral closure."

Comment: I hope you don't mind an extra question: the same example appears to be used [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-2_ring) as a Noetherian non-J-0 ring. As you describe, it sounds like the spectrum looks the same for any field: the zero ideal and the maximal ideals. Even though this makes the spectrum pretty simple, I still have trouble reasoning what the set of regular points would be.  I really have very little intuition for visualizing the spectrum. The only unusual point is the zero ideal.  I would think the other points are regular? How do I know they can't contain a nonempty open set?

Comment: No closed point is regular: the localization at $(x_i^2,x_i^3)$ is isomorphic to $F[x_i^2,x_i^3]_{(x_i^2,x_i^3)}$ for $F=k(x_1,\cdots,x_{i-1},x_{i+1},\cdots)$, which is a 1-dimensional local ring whose maximal ideal is generated by two elements. On the other hand, any non-empty open subset must contain $D(f)$ for some $f\in R$, and every one of these subsets contains a closed point. So there are no open sets which consist only of regular points, contradicting the definition of a J-0 ring. As far as visualizing this, I'm not sure I have much good advice - this is a pretty wild ring!

Comment: thanks! I will try to absorb this…

Comment: Now I'm feeling a little alarmed. By the definitions at the wiki, it's clear that J-2 implies J-1, and I had also thought J-1 implied J-0, but now I'm not so sure. The definition seems to allow for J-1 to hold with the set of regular points being empty, whence it wouldn't be J-0.  It says any local noetherian $\leq 1$ dimension ring is J-1, but thankfully the one we are working on here isn't local.  Is there a reason for there to always be a regular point so that J-1 implies J-0 is OK?

Comment: J-1 might not imply J-0 if the open subset of regular points is empty - think for instance $k[x]/x^2$. It's spectrum is a single non-reduced point, which is not regular. This also shows that there is not generally a reason for there to be regular points - though if you have a reduced ring, the localization at a minimal prime will be a field which is regular, so enforcing reducedness could give you what you want.

Comment: But my big question here is "*was that intentional*?" It is awfully awkward to construct a nomenclature Foo-0, Foo-1, Foo-2 and not have it be a hierarchy.  Maybe the wiki article just omitted "nonempty" from J-1?  I have little access to and expertise with commutative algebra literature with which to crosscheck.

Comment: I mean, I'm not the person who came up with those definitions, so I can't really give you a great answer about the intent. But Matsumura's *Commutative Algebra*, Wikipedia, and [Stacks](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07P7) all agree on the definition of J-0/J-1/J-2 rings, so I think these are the accepted definitions.

Comment: Yes, I am mainly just looking for some insight into whether or not that's the status quo. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Last question: what sorts of sufficient conditions are there out there that guarantee at least one regular point in the spectrum?

Comment: As mentioned above, reducedness (or generic reducedness) is what you want. Then the local ring at a minimal prime is a field which is regular.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't appreciate it earlier. So it seems a reduced J-1 ring is J-0?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.