# Is there a reason a J-1 ring is defined as not necessarily being J-0 ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

In the comments of [a recent solution](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4233905/29335) I noticed that the wikipedia definition of J-1 ring does not necessarily make it a J-0 ring.

[Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/J-2_ring) a commutative ring $R$ is:

> a J-0 ring if the set of regular elements of $Spec(R)$ contains a nonempty open set

> a J-1 ring if the set of regular elements is an open set of $Spec(R)$

The topology is, of course, the usual Zariski topology.

This of course leaves the possibility that the set of regular elements is empty, and that would mean such a ring is J-1 but not J-0. As in the linked post, KReiser has pointed out that Wikipedia, the Stacks project, and Matsumura's books all seem to use the same definition, and it can indeed happen, for example, with $k[x]/(x)^2$.

Now, it seems to me rather abhorrent to choose a nomenclature like J-0, J-1, J-2 which does not wind up being a hierarchy, but I'm not a commutative algebraist, what do I know.

My question here is: are there good reasons commutative algebraists prefer to admit rings with no regular elements in their spectrum to be J-1? Alternatively, why not admit rings with no regular elements in their spectrum to be J-0?

The usual tradeoff would be, of course, that it makes certain statements in the theory easier, but I do not know the particular theory that uses this or have many references to it, so I'd like to ask those of you who are familiar whether or not the tradeoff is justifiable with examples.

(Note: KReiser also provided a useful sufficient condition that J-1 will imply J-0: when $R$ is a reduced ring.)

Comment: At least one consideration is that any reasonable theory of excellence (which involves the J-1 condition) should include finitely-generated algebras over a field as well as complete (Noetherian) local rings. Any complete local ring of depth 0 (of which there are many examples) or similar graded example fits the bill, and should thus be J-1. In particular, an Artinian local ring (which is automatically complete) should be considered J-1. Any of these rings would not have a regular element.

Comment: @metalspringpro ok cool, then the question following that is  “why not drop ‘nonempty’ from J-0?”

Comment: Yes, I suspected that would be the next question. The primary context in which I have seen the J-0, J-1, J-2 conditions resolves around excellence in which case the J-0 condition seems to only come into play for rings that are domains by default. I guess as stated, J-0 is equivalent to saying the singular locus is not dense in $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$, which clearly would be false if one allowed the regular locus to be empty, but I don't know this in and of itself would warrant the restriction.

Comment: We cannot drop "nonempty" from the definition of J-0 since otherwise all commutative rings would be J-0 rings.

Comment: I think the question is intended to be "Why is a ring with an empty regular locus not considered to be J-0?"

Comment: @metalspringpro I also notice that Stacks only defines them for Noetherian rings. Is that something Matsumura does too?

Comment: @rschwieb Yes, Matsumura does the same. The purpose of the notion of excellence is to encompass the "well-behaved" rings that includes most examples from algebraic geometry. Historically, Noetherian rings were a natural first candidate for this class, but Nagata (among others) found many examples of "bad" Noetherian rings. The excellent condition is thus a refinement of the Noetherian condition designed to rule out such examples, with the J conditions used to build up the definition.

Comment: @metalspringpro Seems like the wiki page needs to be updated to include it as a requirement... It seems to be the loner in omitting it.

Comment: @metalspringpro I've asked around a few places, but nobody's taken up the challenge of explaining if admitting empty-regular-locus rings into the J-0 class causes friction with existing theory...

Comment: @rschwieb On both accounts it seems the condition exists almost entirely for the purpose of building/measuring failure of excellence. Since Noetherian is required of excellence one could put forward that whether or not J-0 rings are allowed to be non-Noetherian is a sort of nonissue. But by the same vein one could allow J-0 rings to have an empty regular locus; as far as I can tell this has no discernable impact on the theory of excellence. So maybe a reasonable place to start would be, "What is the J-0 condition used for outside of building/measuring failure of Excellence?"